# Можно ли сделать фон страницы сайта из специальных символов

Tags: html

Можно ли сделать фон страницы сайта из специальных символов, к примеру имеется код &#9720 (треугольник)

Answer (score 1):

Можно.
Заполняете контейнер вашими символами(не знаю зачем вам, проще и лучше картинкой сделать),
выше кладите контейнер с абсолютным позиционированием, и далее в нем располагайте все остальное.

Ваша задумка из разряда особо изысканных извращений.